# Getting a sum from multiple inputs using a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, sum

I have to write a program that uses a for loop to ask how many floors are in a hotel, then ask the user for the number of rooms on each floor and the number of rooms occupied. At the end I'm to add up all the rooms, how many are occupied and not occupied, and give percentages based on those numbers. So far all I have is the loop, and my sum feature now gives me outrageous numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{

int floor, room, occupy, total_unoccupy, total_occupy, total_room;

cout << "How many floors are in the hotel?\n";
cin >> floor;


   for ( ;floor >= 1; floor--)
   {
      cout << "How many rooms are on floor " << floor <<  "?" << endl;
      cin >> room;
      cout << "How many of these rooms are occupied?" <<endl;
      cin >> occupy;
   }
total_room += room;

cout << "The total number of rooms are " << total_room << "." << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `total_room += room;` inside the `for` loop.

```
for ( ;floor >= 1; floor--) {
    cout << "How many rooms are on floor " << floor <<  "?" << endl;
    cin >> room;
    total_room += room;
    cout << "How many of these rooms are occupied?" <<endl;
    cin >> occupy;
    total_occupy += room;
    total_unoccupy += room-occupy;
}
```

Also, you need to change this line:

```
int floor, room, occupy, total_unoccupy, total_occupy, total_room;
```

To this:

```
int floor = 0, room = 0, occupy = 0, total_unoccupy = 0, total_occupy = 0,  total_room = 0;
```

Comment: That still gave me a large number. Using my same "total_room" statement I had 3 floors with 6 rooms each all occupied and received an output in the thousands.

Comment: @EatMyPeacock Read the second part of my answer.  Part of the problem is that you're not summing ALL the floors.  The other part of the problem is you're not initializing your variables.  While `floor`, `room`, and `occupy` aren't as important to initialize (since you're using them only after taking user input), it's vitally crucial that you initialize `total_unoccupy`, `total_occupy`, and `total_room`.

Comment: I absolutely missed that second part. Thank you!!

Comment: Np, just be sure to accept the answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the variables like **total_occupy = 0** etc... otherwise you can have unexpected results.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

nothing left to be answered thanks for nhgr
Moreover, in case multiplication, you need to initialize the total variable as 1.